# Efficient way to convert from roll, pitch yaw to geometry_msgs::Quaternion

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to convert roll, pitch and yaw angles to a `geometry_msgs::Quaternion` object, which is appropriate for publishing, I currently do the following:

`tf2::Quaternion quaternion_tf2;`

`quaternion_tf2.setRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);`

`geometry_msgs::Quaternion quaternion = tf2::toMsg(quaternion_tf2);`

However, is there a more efficient way to do this? In particular, is there a way to bypass having to create a `tf2::Quaternion` object, and instead simply initialize the `geometry_msgs::Quaternion` object with roll, pitch and yaw using something similar to the `.setRPY()` function that is available for `tf2::Quaternion`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365102/efficient-way-to-convert-from-roll,-pitch-yaw-to-geometry_msgs::quaternion/) by [JeffR1992](https://answers.ros.org/users/41866/jeffr1992/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

As far as I know, there are no real constructors (in the sens that they fill the values) for ros messages, because it would be to complicated to do (because the classes for ros messages are automatically generated from the .msg files).
And according to the following git issue, it seems that the idea was definitively abondoned for ROS 1 (development is now foccused on ROS 2). :

> https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/148

If you use a lot of quaternions, you can simply write your own function :

```
geometry_msgs::Quaternion quaternion_from_rpy(double roll, double pitch, double yaw)
{
  tf2::Quaternion quaternion_tf2;
  quaternion_tf2.setRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
  geometry_msgs::Quaternion quaternion = tf2::toMsg(quaternion_tf2);
  return quaternion;
}
```

and use it to creat your quaternions

If you don't want to write your own function, you can create directly a constructor with arguments for the tf2::Quaternion in order to have one line less. They are 3 options according to

> http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1Quaternion.html

```
Quaternion (const tf2Scalar &x, const tf2Scalar &y, const tf2Scalar &z, const tf2Scalar &w)
Quaternion (const Vector3 &axis, const tf2Scalar &angle)
Quaternion (const tf2Scalar &yaw, const tf2Scalar &pitch, const tf2Scalar &roll) __attribute__((deprecated))
```

Note however that the one you would like to use (the one from yaw, pitch and roll) is deprecated. So up to you to decide if you still want to use it or not

---

Originally posted by [felixN](https://answers.ros.org/users/59005/felixn/) with karma: 108 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1